# C++ Templates : Getting wrong results (output) with MInGW

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, mingw

I hesitate to ask this question because there is probably something wrong with my C++ template program but this problem has been bugging me for the past couple of hours. I am running the exact same program on Visual C++ and Mingw-g++ compilers but only VC2010 is giving me the expected results. I am not proficient C++ programmer by any means so not getting any error messages from either compilers is even more frustrating.

Edit : I did mingw-get upgrade after failing to resolve the error. I was running g++ 4.5.2 and now I have version 4.7.2 but the problem persists.

Late Update - I did a complete uninstall of MinGW platform, manually removed every folder and then installed TDM-GCC but the problem persists. Maybe there is some conflict with my Windows Installation. I have installed Cygwin and g++ 4.5.3 for the time being (It is working) as OS reinstallation isn't really an option right now. Thanks for all the help.

Here is my code. (Header File itertest.h)

```
#ifndef ITERTEST_H
#define ITERTEST_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class fft_data{
public: 
vector<T> re;
vector<T> im;

};

template <typename T>
void inline twiddle(fft_data<T> &vec,int N,int radix){
// Calculates twiddle factors for radix-2
T PI2 = (T) 6.28318530717958647692528676655900577;
T theta = (T) PI2/N;
vec.re.resize(N/radix,(T) 0.0);
vec.im.resize(N/radix,(T) 0.0);
vec.re[0] = (T) 1.0;

for (int K = 1; K < N/radix; K++) {
    vec.re[K] = (T) cos(theta * K);
    vec.im[K] = (T) sin(theta * K);
}


}

template <typename T>
void inline sh_radix5_dif(fft_data<T> &x,fft_data<T> &wl, int q, int sgn) {
int n = x.re.size();
int L = (int) pow(5.0, (double)q);
int Ls = L / 5;
int r = n / L;

T c1 = 0.30901699437;
T c2 = -0.80901699437;
T s1 = 0.95105651629;
T s2 = 0.58778525229;

T tau0r,tau0i,tau1r,tau1i,tau2r,tau2i,tau3r,tau3i;
T tau4r,tau4i,tau5r,tau5i;
T br,bi,cr,ci,dr,di,er,ei;

fft_data<T> y = x;
T wlr,wli,wl2r,wl2i,wl3r,wl3i,wl4r,wl4i;
int lsr = Ls*r;

for (int j = 0; j < Ls; j++) {
    int ind = j*r;
    wlr = wl.re[ind];
    wli = wl.im[ind];

    wl2r = wlr*wlr - wli*wli;
    wl2i = 2.0*wlr*wli;

    wl3r = wl2r*wlr - wli*wl2i;
    wl3i= wl2r*wli + wl2i*wlr;

    wl4r = wl2r*wl2r - wl2i*wl2i;
    wl4i = 2.0*wl2r*wl2i;

    for (int k =0; k < r; k++) {
        int index = k*L+j;
        int index1 = index+Ls;
        int index2 = index1+Ls;
        int index3 = index2+Ls;
        int index4 = index3+Ls;

        tau0r = y.re[index1] + y.re[index4];
        tau0i = y.im[index1] + y.im[index4];

        tau1r = y.re[index2] + y.re[index3];
        tau1i = y.im[index2] + y.im[index3];

        tau2r = y.re[index1] - y.re[index4];
        tau2i = y.im[index1] - y.im[index4];

        tau3r = y.re[index2] - y.re[index3];
        tau3i = y.im[index2] - y.im[index3];

        tau4r = c1 * tau0r + c2 * tau1r;
        tau4i = c1 * tau0i + c2 * tau1i;

        tau5r = sgn * ( s1 * tau2r + s2 * tau3r);
        tau5i = sgn * ( s1 * tau2i + s2 * tau3i);

        br = y.re[index] + tau4r + tau5i;
        bi = y.im[index] + tau4i - tau5r;

        er = y.re[index] + tau4r - tau5i;
        ei = y.im[index] + tau4i + tau5r;

        tau4r = c2 * tau0r + c1 * tau1r;
        tau4i = c2 * tau0i + c1 * tau1i;

        tau5r = sgn * ( s2 * tau2r - s1 * tau3r);
        tau5i = sgn * ( s2 * tau2i - s1 * tau3i);

        cr = y.re[index] + tau4r + tau5i;
        ci = y.im[index] + tau4i - tau5r;

        dr = y.re[index] + tau4r - tau5i;
        di = y.im[index] + tau4i + tau5r;

        int indexo = k*Ls+j;
        int indexo1 = indexo+lsr;
        int indexo2 = indexo1+lsr;
        int indexo3 = indexo2+lsr;
        int indexo4 = indexo3+lsr;

        x.re[indexo]= y.re[index] + tau0r + tau1r;
        x.im[indexo]= y.im[index] + tau0i + tau1i;

        x.re[indexo1] = wlr*br - wli*bi;
        x.im[indexo1] = wlr*bi + wli*br;

        x.re[indexo2] = wl2r*cr - wl2i*ci;
        x.im[indexo2] = wl2r*ci + wl2i*cr;

        x.re[indexo3] = wl3r*dr - wl3i*di;
        x.im[indexo3] = wl3r*di + wl3i*dr;

        x.re[indexo4] = wl4r*er - wl4i*ei;
        x.im[indexo4] = wl4r*ei + wl4i*er;


    }

}

}

template <typename T>
void inline fftsh_radix5_dif(fft_data<T> &data,int sgn, unsigned int N) {
//unsigned int len = data.re.size(); 

int num = (int) ceil(log10(static_cast<double>(N))/log10(5.0));

//indrev(data,index);
fft_data<T> twi;

twiddle(twi,N,5);
if (sgn == 1) {
    transform(twi.im.begin(), twi.im.end(),twi.im.begin(),bind1st(multiplies<T>(),(T) -1.0));
}

for (int i=num; i > 0; i--) {
sh_radix5_dif(data,twi,i,sgn);


}


}


#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include "itertest.h"

using namespace std;



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int N = 25;
//vector<complex<double> > sig1;
fft_data<double> sig1;
for (int i =0; i < N; i++){
//sig1.push_back(complex<double>((double)1.0, 0.0));
    //sig2.re.push_back((double) i);
    //sig2.im.push_back((double) i+2);
    sig1.re.push_back((double) 1);
    sig1.im.push_back((double) 0);
}


fftsh_radix5_dif(sig1,1,N);



for (int i =0; i < N; i++){
    cout << sig1.re[i] << " " << sig1.im[i] << endl;
}

cin.get();

return 0;

}
```

The expected Output (which I am getting from VC2010)

```
25 0
4.56267e-016 -2.50835e-016
2.27501e-016 -3.58484e-016
1.80101e-017 -2.86262e-016
... rest 21 rows same as the last three rows ( < 1e-015)
```

The Output from Mingw-g++

```
20 0
4.94068e-016 -2.10581e-016
2.65385e-016 -3.91346e-016
-5.76751e-017 -2.93654e-016
5 0
-1.54508 -4.75528
-3.23032e-017 1.85061e-017
-4.68253e-017 -1.18421e-016
-6.32003e-017 -2.05833e-016
1.11022e-016 0
4.04508 -2.93893
8.17138e-017 6.82799e-018
3.5246e-017 9.06767e-017
-6.59101e-017 -1.62762e-016
1.11022e-016 0
4.04508 2.93893
-6.28467e-017 6.40636e-017
1.79807e-016 3.34411e-017
-6.94919e-017 -1.05831e-016
1.11022e-016 0
-1.54508 4.75528
5.70402e-017 -1.68674e-017
-1.36169e-016 -8.30473e-017
-9.75639e-017 3.40359e-016
1.11022e-016 0
```

Comment: I'm sure that you can narrow this down some more for us.

Comment: The problem is that the exact same code is giving me different results on different compilers. Neither is showing any errors either.

Comment: Yeah, you said that already.

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant but g++ on Linux says: itertest.h:153:87: error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)

Comment: Avoid `using namespace std;` in a header

Comment: @parkydr not relevant. I fixed the typo already

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is this the Transform(.. .) line ?

Comment: @raf please? I [fixed it already](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14802642/revisions)

Answer (score 1):

There must be something wrong with your MinGW installation. You might have an out-of-date, buggy version of GCC. The unofficial TDM-GCC distribution usually has a more up-to-date version: http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/

When I compile your code with GCC 4.6.3 on Ubuntu, it produces the output below, which appears to match the VC2010 output exactly (but I can't verify this, since you didn't provide it in full). Adding the options `-O3 -ffast-math -march=native` doesn't seem to change anything.

Note that I had to fix an obvious typo in `fftsh_radix5_dif` (missing closing angle bracket in the list of template arguments to multiply), but I assume you do not have it in your code, since it wouldn't compile at all.

```
25 0
4.56267e-16 -2.50835e-16
2.27501e-16 -3.58484e-16
1.80101e-17 -2.86262e-16
-5.76751e-17 -1.22566e-16
8.88178e-16 0
9.45774e-17 1.19479e-17
1.27413e-16 -5.04465e-17
7.97139e-17 -9.63575e-17
1.35142e-17 -7.08438e-17
8.88178e-16 0
4.84283e-17 4.54772e-17
1.02473e-16 2.63107e-17
1.02473e-16 -2.63107e-17
4.84283e-17 -4.54772e-17
8.88178e-16 0
1.35142e-17 7.08438e-17
7.97139e-17 9.63575e-17
1.27413e-16 5.04465e-17
9.45774e-17 -1.19479e-17
8.88178e-16 0
-5.76751e-17 1.22566e-16
1.80101e-17 2.86262e-16
2.27501e-16 3.58484e-16
4.56267e-16 2.50835e-16
```

Comment: ...or the wrong executable is being run.

Comment: Funny, you tested with exactly the same added flags as I did (only I used more recent GCC version). I haven't heard TDM being _recommended_  in any serious quarters, though.

Comment: @DrewDormann I _bet_ you wanted to post that at the question?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly the answer I am getting on VC2010. I upgraded MinGW installation but it is still not working. I also have some additional mingw binaries on my system that came with QT4.8, Haskell etc. I have tried to remove them from the system path and it still hasn't worked. I guess I will have to do a complete reinstallation.

Answer (score 0):

Check the creation date of the executable you're running.

You may be running an earlier draft of your program.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. I created a separate project on two different IDEs + build the source code in a separate folder from the command line. Same problem.